# How to edit/save Camel source XML using hawtio?

Tags: hawtio

I upgrade the `hawtio version: 1.4.67` to `Hawtio Core 3.2.26`

The version `1.x` I can edit and save the XML router from Spring DSL.

[image]

The version `3.2` the option `source` tab doesn't appear!

[image]

There is a option to enable the `source` tab or another way to edit and save a Spring DSL router?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Source tab is not yet ported to v2 for technical reason. The Hawtio development team will recover the feature in the near future.